# Bjarne Stroustrup programming practices and principles chapter 7

Tags: c++

I have a question about logic flow:

```
I'm trying to create a calculator functionality that: 
1.lets you assign a declare a variable (eg, let x = 5;) 
2. that will also let you reassign a value (eg, x = 10;)
3. will let you use values in expressions (eg, x + 5; returns 15)
```

The bottom function statement() is supposed to decide if  Token Token_stream::get()
   returns a declaration, reassignment, or expression then run the appropriate code.

In making it so that Token_stream::get() returns name to statement()
   and calls the reassignment. I lost the functionality to
  have an expression() start with a name. Eg. If I write

x + 5;

It will throw an error from assignment because it reads the x and looks for a =
instead of calling expression.

I want to create special token for assignment to use in statement() if Token Token_stream::get() reads a string followed by a '=', but then put the name back into the input stream so I can grab if for the assignment. Does any have any suggestions?

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Token Token_stream::get()
        {
            if (full) { full=false; return buffer; }
            char ch;
            cin >> ch;
            switch (ch) {
            case '(':
            case ')':
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
            case '%':
            case ';':
            case '=':
            case ',': 
                return Token(ch);
            case '.':
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
            {   cin.unget();
                double val;
                cin >> val;
                return Token(number,val);
            }
            default:
                if (isalpha(ch)) {
                    string s;
                    s += ch;
                      while(cin.get(ch) && (isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch))||        ch    =='_' )   s+=ch;
                    cin.unget();
                    if (s ==   "let")   return Token(let);
                    if (s == "const")   return Token(constant);   
                    if (s ==     "q")   return Token(quit);
                    if (s ==  "sqrt")   return Token(square_root); 
                    if (s ==   "pow")   return Token(exponent);       
                    return Token(name,s);
                }
                error("Bad token");
            }
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        double statement()
        {
            Token t = ts.get();
            switch(t.kind) 
                {
                case let: 
                    return declaration();

                case name:
                    ts.unget(t);
                    return assigment();

                case constant: 
                    return declare_constant();

                default:
                    ts.unget(t);
                    return expression();
                }
        }
        //----
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put error handling logic inside a tokenizer class - it's supposed to be a pretty dumb text muncher that just splits it on whitespaces and returns tokens to the caller.

So lets say you start parsing a statement and your tokeninizer returns `let`. Now you know that what follows is supposed to be a declaration. The next token should be a unique name of a variable that doesn't exists yet. So you call `Token_stream::get()` again and see what you get. On success, you get the next token and see if you get a `=`. Etc.

Similarly - you get a name of a variable as a first token of a statement. You check whether it has been declared yet and report an error if it hasn't. You check another token. It's supposed be an operator of some sort (that probably includes `=`). If you get it, you start looking for a valid term (a value, another variable, an expression...). Etc.